# fb messanger api - how my fb app can send messages from opt-in user?

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, express

I have node express test server ([express-4.x-facebook-example](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example)) that users can log in with their FB account.

Now, I have a test app in FB, and I'd like to send messages on behalf of the user.

What exactly I should get from logged-in user details to initate the send message?

for example in [fb-messanger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb-messenger) what is the token param? 
is it something I take

Comment: You can not send messages between users via API. And to reply to a user in a messenger bot conversation requires that the user _starts_ the conversation.

Comment: thanks, so what is the "send" function here? is it only for bots developers? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference

Comment: That is for Messenger Bots to send their replies.